# Function undefined error on link click

Tags: javascript

I am getting error `SelectAll is not defined` when i click on `select all` button.

```
function selectAll(){
$('#langtabs').data('tabSelect').selectAll();
}
```

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yun97ecf/17/)

Comment: Your `selectAll` function definition is wrapped inside a `$(function() {/*...*/});`, so it is not available outside of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move this function

```
function selectAll(){
   $('#langtabs').data('tabSelect').selectAll();
}
```

Outside the `$(function(){ .... });` otherwise it wont be in global scope which is where `onclick` will be looking for it.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yun97ecf/19/)